# Show 2 initial items in a list view and then show all the items

Tags: android, listview

I have a list view which has to be populated with multiple elements. Initially, I want to display the first two elements and subsequently show the other elements when the user begins to scroll.

The code that I have is as follows:

`ListView in XML`

```
<LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/layout"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/options"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    </LinearLayout>
```

`ListView Item Definition`

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="52dp"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:background="@color/white">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:inputType="textMultiLine"
        android:lines="2" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Adapter :

```
String[] mobileArray = {"Android", "iPhone","Windows", "Mac", "Moto", "Oneplus", "Random A", "Random B", "Random C", "Random D"};

ListView listView = (ListView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.options);

LinearLayout responseLayout = (LinearLayout) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.layout);

ArrayAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(), R.layout.item, R.id.text,mobileArray);

listView.setAdapter(adapter);

listView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

responseLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
```

In this example I want `Android` and `iPhone` to be visible initially and then the user should be able to scroll to the other options.

Currently all the options are visible, where am I going wrong?

Comment: 1. You have only four items, i believe you never get scrollbars to scroll on ui.. 2. You can do it by setting scroll listener and when you reach end then add two more items to array and call `notifyDatasetChanged();`

Comment: @bharat I can add more items to the adapter, assume 10 items, in that case what do I do?

Comment: then follow this ... You can do it by setting scroll listener to listview and when you reach end then add two more items to array and call notifyDatasetChanged();... this just like pagination when you reach end of the listview add more items to it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just create your own custom adapter and override `getCount` method so it return 2 when it is necessary. Then, when you need to show all the items you should set flag that notify that you have more items and after that call `adapter.notifydatasetchanged`

Something like this:

```
    class CustomAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    private List elements;
    private boolean showAll;
    private int resId;

    public CustomAdapter(List elements, boolean showAll, int resId) {
        this.elements = elements;
        this.showAll = showAll;
        this.resId = resId;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        if (elements == null) {
            return 0;
        } else if (elements.size() < 2 || showAll) {
            return elements.size();
        } else {
            return 2;
        }
    }

    public void setShowAll(boolean showAll) {
        this.showAll = showAll;
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return elements.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        //Todo inflate your element
        return null;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I didn't try that, but what if you make custom adapter and in getView() will return null when you don't want item to be visible?

Answer (score 0):

May be you need to assign list cell height dynamically. In order to display only first two items, each cell height should be half of the screen size.

```
Point size = new Point();
    Display display=getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
    int screenWidth;
    int screenHeight;
    if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT<Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB_MR2)
    {
        screenWidth=display.getWidth();
        screenHeight=display.getHeight();
    }
    else
    {
        display.getSize(size);
        screenWidth = size.x;
        screenHeight=size.y;
    }
int halfScreenHeight = (int)(screenHeight*0.5);
```

You need to set the halfscreenHeight for the list item relativelayout.